# WP8.1 How to do multiple-screen support application?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm new for WP8.1 application developer. i'm done one news based application. its working fine all 480x800 devices. but, in this application not working full screen in higher device like winPhone1320(720x1280). it's diplaying left corner of screen (480x800) portion only.

How i make it full screen, any thing i need to change in app.xaml file.

I don't have any idea about this doubt.

Comment: Looks like you might have some hard coded width and height values?

Comment: no i'm not hard coded.

Comment: Give us your XAML markup